# Magic Mouse 2 scrolling crashes apps on Big Sur

Tags: mouse, big-sur, macos

I'm experiencing really annoying issue on Big Sur (It worked like charm on Catalina).

**I'm unable to scroll with Magic Mouse 2**:

- in "subwindows" of applications, you know the "pop up" ones. This means System preferences crashes for example, among other apps.
- In Finder windows, whole Finder crashes and restarts

**IT DOESN'T HAPPEN WITH:**

- touchpad scrolling
- "generic" mouse with scrollwheel.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: It is pretty much the same in every app, it blows up in different threads number tho...

```
Crashed Thread:        13  com.apple.NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    LIBSYSTEM, [0x2]

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode
assertion failure: "currentTime >= wakeUpTime" -> %lld

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20310e7e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203111f0 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043dbe7 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043c2ba __CFRunLoopRun + 1315
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043b6be CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff286a7fd0 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff286a7dcc ReceiveNextEventCommon + 709
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff286a7aef _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c54f85 _DPSNextEvent + 883
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c5374b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1366
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c45bda -[NSApplication run] + 586
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22c19f31 NSApplicationMain + 816
12  com.apple.Console               0x000000010be46129 0x10be41000 + 20777
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20360631 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20310e7e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203111f0 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043dbe7 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043c2ba __CFRunLoopRun + 1315
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043b6be CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff211c5fa1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21254384 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
7   com.apple.ConsoleKit            0x00007fff6f55a264 __24-[CSKDeviceManager init]_block_invoke + 175
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff21377c87 __NSThread__block_start__ + 49
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20345950 _pthread_start + 224
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2034147b thread_start + 15

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203191fe __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204646b3 __CFSocketManager + 644
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20345950 _pthread_start + 224
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2034147b thread_start + 15

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20341458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20310e7e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203111f0 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043dbe7 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043c2ba __CFRunLoopRun + 1315
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2043b6be CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22ddb36d _NSEventThread + 124
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20345950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2034147b thread_start + 15

Thread 13 Crashed:: com.apple.NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20332792 __abort_with_payload + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203341d9 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2033420b abort_with_payload + 9
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff2029771b _os_crash_fmt.cold.1 + 55
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff2022a105 _os_crash_fmt + 154
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff235c7043 run_monitor_thread + 1146
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20345950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2034147b thread_start + 15

Thread 13 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000002000209  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000700008ad1db8  rdx: 0x0000700008ad1e70
  rdi: 0x0000000000000012  rsi: 0x0000000000000002  rbp: 0x0000700008ad1e00  rsp: 0x0000700008ad1db8
   r8: 0x0000600000ca64c0   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000054  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000054  r13: 0x0000700008ad1e70  r14: 0x0000000000000002  r15: 0x0000000000000012
  rip: 0x00007fff20332792  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00000001086b8000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000209
Trap Number:     133

Thread 13 instruction stream not available.

Thread 13 last branch register state not available.
```